# Whitenoise collectstatic failing on none existent file

Tags: python, django, whitenoise

I seem to be getting an issue with serving running collectstatic when whitenoise is enabled. I keep getting an error about a missing file - not quite sure why.

Here is the fill traceback

```
Post-processing 'third/vendors/owl-carousel/assets/owl.carousel.css' failed!

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/thegqvow/virtualenv/gradientboostmvp/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 371, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/thegqvow/virtualenv/gradientboostmvp/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 365, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/thegqvow/virtualenv/gradientboostmvp/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/thegqvow/virtualenv/gradientboostmvp/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 335, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/thegqvow/virtualenv/gradientboostmvp/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 189, in handle
    collected = self.collect()
  File "/home/thegqvow/virtualenv/gradientboostmvp/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 135, in collect
    raise processed
  File "/home/thegqvow/virtualenv/gradientboostmvp/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/storage.py", line 296, in _post_process
    content = pattern.sub(converter, content)
  File "/home/thegqvow/virtualenv/gradientboostmvp/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/storage.py", line 197, in converter
    force=True, hashed_files=hashed_files,
  File "/home/thegqvow/virtualenv/gradientboostmvp/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/storage.py", line 134, in _url
    hashed_name = hashed_name_func(*args)
  File "/home/thegqvow/virtualenv/gradientboostmvp/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/storage.py", line 345, in _stored_name
    cache_name = self.clean_name(self.hashed_name(name))
  File "/home/thegqvow/virtualenv/gradientboostmvp/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/storage.py", line 94, in hashed_name
    raise ValueError("The file '%s' could not be found with %r." % (filename, self))
ValueError: The file 'third/vendors/owl-carousel/assets/owl.video.play.png' could not be found with <django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.ManifestStaticFilesStorage object at 0x7f5018ab78d0>.
```

Comment: Did you check that the file exists: 'third/vendors/owl-carousel/assets/owl.video.play.png'

Comment: @hendrikschneider  I removed all references to that file in owl.carousel.css

Comment: Did you try to delete your static files folder to ensure that no old is being used?